# Are accepted papers going to be plagiarism checked?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

here's my friend's situation, he submitted a journal paper then gave up after some time and thought it's going to be rejected after a few rejections in an open access journal,he put some parts (as it is), in a conference paper and submitted this work, to his surprise he got acceptance in both.

I asked him to cancel his conference submission not to risk a potential problem with his open access journal submission. He didn't take this seriously and moved on with both.

what are the chances of him getting caught in this situation, given that it's just about 8 months before he will graduate?

Comment: This question reads "what are the chances my friend is going to be caught cheating?". The proper question should be "how can I persuade my friend not to cheat?".

Comment: Why would a conference submission conflict with a paper submission?

Comment: @AzorAhai while in some disciplines conference papers "don't count", on other disciplines they are expected to contain novel, unpublished research, and having such an overlap would be pretty much equivalent to publishing the same paper in two journals which both expected that the submission was novel and unpublished.

Comment: "Yes, let's all have crazy rules about how human knowledge has to advance..." Sigh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most of the open access journals, it takes less time to put the article online (one of the pros for choosing open access). It might take less than one month, even some cases, after paying the article processing charge, the journal put the author submitted version online.

Now, for the conference paper, I guess the time difference between the acceptance date and actual conference date is not more than six months. In several cases, the author needs to upload the final camera ready version to the conference submission system in advance. If the conference maintains a good ethics, then the paper will be automatically verified with similarly checking softwares before sending the papers to the proceedings publication department — during this period, the open access article will be online.

You get the idea on the consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention that it was a late submission for the conference paper, so according to the approximate publication time you provided the OA paper will still go first,now it is unlikely that the conference paper is going to be plagiarism checked again after the presentation, right?

Comment: What is the timeline to upload the final camera-ready version to the conference? In all cases, it will definitely create an issue no matter when they get online. Since OA article has been accepted, why will anyone go for conference paper with less content and registration fees unless there are any requirements for the graduation?

Comment: The camera-ready version deadline was a month ago, for graduation requirements one of the two submissions will be enough since our time is very limited, I am trying now to learn something and provide him with educated advises as we both are beginners.

Comment: @Mithun I think that the question is posted wrong. There is a high chance that this is going to be discovered at some point... And even if this is discovered AFTER graduation, it will likely be a big problem.

Comment: @NickS agreed. That is why I said it will create an issue no matter when they get online. We should not encourage these double submissions.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, What a risky decision! This might give him a lot of "free" troubles in the long run since both publishers, sooner or later, they will expose the paper in front of search engines and people will start to complain his work (check for that using this [Free Academic Plagiarism Checker Tool](https://scholarplagiarism.com/) ). 
Chances he'll be blacklisted from all major publishers :/

Comment: Exactly. Somewhere in the Internet, I saw IEEE regularly publishes prohibited list of authors (some of the authors are prohibited for further submission for a year or many). I am too lazy to put the link of prohibited author list by IEEE here.

Answer (score 0):

That's very risky. Even if a student graduates and is not caught for plagiarising, he may still have issues after graduation. It may lead to a degree to be revoked. There are a lot of professional plagiarism detection tools (*like Turnitin, Unicheck, Scholar Plagiarism*), that can easily detect any type of cheating.